# The drop-down list of the VS Code menu shows scrambled code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

```
版本: 1.50.1 (user setup)
提交: d2e414d9e4239a252d1ab117bd7067f125afd80a
日期: 2020-10-13T15:06:15.712Z
Electron: 9.2.1
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.16299
```

System：Window 10

[image]

The latest version of Vscode downloaded from the official website has been reinstalled twice.

Comment: have you tried disabling `Hardware Acceleration`, it cause render errors sometimes

Comment: Thank you, it has been successfully resolved.
Open the command panel with `ctrp+shift+p`, find the `Preferences: Configure Runtime Arguments` command, and add `"disable-hardware-acceleration": true`.